# What about StackOverflow questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

What about situation where the question already has an answer on StackOverflow (eg. [How to filter items by language in Treelist field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-to-filter-items-by-language-in-treelist-field))

I almost copied one-to-one someone's answer because as we discussed before we don't want to include only links in answers. And this makes me feel bad about myslef. On the other hand I know that someone there is waiting for the answer.

How do we want to deal with such duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can answer the question, answer it! Remember that part of the purpose for a private beta is to test if there is a ***need*** for this site. If this sites does not bring something unique to the network, there may not be a need for this site at all.

Consider also that Sitecore programming is still on topic on Stack Overflow, so we have no cause to remove content from another site and the reputation/ownership that goes with it.

The wholesale importing of content from elsewhere is not really a viable way to build a new site. Questions imported from elsewhere would likely be orphaned when the author doesn't have an account there; usernames are greyed-out as anonymous, tags wouldn't match, posts may not follow the posting guidelines here, and there's nobody receiving the inbox notifications if someone requests clarifications or improvements — anonymous content always has that odd, back-dated feel of long-forgotten questions that no one really cares about any longer.

That is why we do not copy content from other sites.

And please do not solicit content or users by posting comment on Stack Overflow; that is not allowed. There is generally no problem with a little crossover between sites, but I wouldn't copy questions from Stack Overflow as a way of filling the site with text. Questions should be asked out of actual need by the folks having the problem, but simply copying text from elsewhere misses the point of having a Stack Exchange site.

See [**Respect the community - your own, and others’**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Answer (score 3):

Excellent question; many have approached today asking variations of the same thing.

For right now; what you did seems to be the ideal. We're in Closed Beta, and we can't really do much else.

Later on though; we do get more options available. For instance, moderators (high rep users) on StackOverflow will get an ability to defer questions from SO to this site - essentially migrating the (new) questions over. For existing questions, I am not sure what the options are and what options we might get. But I'm trying to find out.

In my opinion; your approach is what we should stick to right now. And then see what the tools allow us, once we're a little bit more solidified.

Comment: Hopefully we will be able to migrate SO questions here, the we can close the questions on here as Duplicate.